# Conflicting .jars in my fat jar vs Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'd love to use the features of json-io 4.10.1. Unfortunately, my version of hadoop (2.8.4) bundles version 2.5.1. When my app runs, it pulls in json-io from /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn-lib instead of the classes bundled in my application .jar.

This newer version, for example, does not have the method JsonReader.jsonToJava with the second argument that accepts parameters, and this version does a better job of mapping my objects to/from json.

When executing the application, I get an error that the appropriate method could not be found. Ultimately as a stopgap, I removed the file /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn-lib/json-io-2.5.1.jar and the application found the "local" version and ran successfully.

So in my pom.xml, I declare json-io as a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
  <version>4.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And I've configured the shade plugin to create a fat .jar. The resulting jar does contain JsonReader.class from the correct version of json-io.

This older jar is directly on hadoop's classpath (/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn-lib/*).

I expect the class loader to find the bundled JsonReader.class, but it's pulling the one from the classpath.

Comment: Best I can tell, from my rather poor understanding of the subject, is that json-io is already loaded somewhere along the way and the classloader won't re-load it for me.

Comment: Seems to be related to [this question](https://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/general/104e02c7gz/custom-class-loader-for-hadoop-m-r-jobs) which resulted ultimately in patch [MAPREDUCE-1700](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12563283/MAPREDUCE-1700.patch) which allows a setClassLoader for an application in version 2.9+. Not quite helpful for me stuck in 2.8.4

Comment: why don't you add the bundled version(one you don't to be used) to excludes of hadoop-yarn dependeny in you pom file?

Comment: @epcpu, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The yarn launcher loads json-io before it hands off to my app.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you can exclude deeper dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-yarn</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This should prevent the pulling of the other `json-io` lib.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, @Sascha, but I think perhaps I was unclear. The *opposite* of this is happening. I am correctly including the newer json-io in maven and bundling it with shade. The yarn loader (which runs the mapreduce app) already has JsonReader (for example) loaded from the older version of json-io because that is what it uses. Basically, I need to reload an already loaded class (I think).

Comment: Then you would have to look for a unique class (e.g. SpecialClass) that is in the jar that also contains your desired JSonReader version but not in the other jar. Then you could load the class via `SpecialClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("my.json.JSonReader");`